Power Analysis for Multiple Treatments per Respondent in Survey Experiment
I am running a vignette survey experiment with 6 total treatment options (5 treatments, 1 control), where each respondent randomly receives 2 of the treatment options and answers the same set of questions after each one of these treatments. These treatment rounds are independent of each other, so there should be no carry-over effects between trials.
I want to then run analysis in 2 ways:
T-test for estimated treatment effects between treatment (and control) groups across respondents
(paired) T-test for estimated treatment effects within respondent (so scores from 1 treatment vs another, within respondent)
The T-tests should be two-sided.
I want to do a power analysis (ideally in R) to determine how many respondents I need for 80% power and weak effects. I have been trying to use the pwr package, but I am struggling to conceptualize how the multiple treatments per respondent affect the power calculation. Do the 2 treatments just allow me to divide the number of necessary respondents determined after the power calculation? Or, do they alter how I should program it?
Also, if I were to block randomize respondents prior to treatment, does that have any bearing on this?

So you have two rounds of surveys, and it's a panel so you have the same people twice, right? For the control, are these people control in both rounds, or is control just randomly assigned to some people in round one but possibly to other people in round two?

Thanks for the response! It's not a panel, it's one round of survey. The respondents each received two of 6 possible options for separate questions of the same survey (same date). Yes, the control is randomized just like the other treatment options, with equal chance 1/6 of receiving control in the first or second round. The only fixed scenario is respondents cannot receive the same treatment/control option twice. For the within-respondent t-test, it's like a panel in that I am measuring within respondent, but it's not about time change, just difference between two treatment effects

You might be able to run the power calculations using the Superpower package for power calculations in ANOVAs (they also have a shiny app https://shiny.ieis.tue.nl/anova_power/)
Another way would be to formulate this as a multilevel model and use simr or mixedpower. A multilevel model for your design might be formulated like this:
model<-lmer(outcome ~ treatment + (1|id), data=data)

Where you'd test the treatment effect while accounting for the repeated nature of the data using the random intecept (1|id) (you might want/need to also include random intercept of treatment, (1|treatment)).
A quick example in simr with just the random intercept of participant:
library(simr)
library(lme4)

#create mock data with 60 participants and 2 measurements per participant
id1<-1:60
occasion<-1:2
id<-rep(id1, each=2)
occ<-rep(occasion, times=60)
treat<-LETTERS[1:6]
treatment<-rep(treat, times=10, replace=T) #this doesn't randomize the treatment placement though, not sure how to do that while making sure nobody gets the same treatment twice
simdf<-data.frame(id, occ, treatment)
head(simdf) #check it resembles your data structure

#define fixed effects (based on your idea of how much treatments should differ from each other)

fix<-c(3, 0.2, 0.5, -.01, 1, -.8) #these are the intercept (i.e. treatment A mean, you can treat A as the control treatment) and B-F differences from A, as in any regression with a categorical predictor

#set random intercept variance (how much of the outcome variance you believe will be due to participant effects)

rand<-0.3

#set residual variance

res<-1

#create the simulated model

modelsim<-makeLmer(y ~ treatment + (1|id), data=simdf, fixef=fix, VarCorr=rand, sigma=res)
summary(modelsim)

#run the power calculations for any differences between any groups:

powerSim(modelsim, test=fixed("treatment", "lr"))

#power for detecting A-B difference

powerSim(modelsim, test=fixed("treatmentB", "z"))

EDIT.

#test many sample sizes (here ns 20, 30, 40 and 50):

pc1<-powerCurve(modelsim, test=fixed("treatment", "lr"), along = "id", breaks=c(20, 30, 40, 50))
pc2<-powerCurve(modelsim, test=fixed("treatmentB", "z"), along="id", breaks=c(20,30,40,50))
plot(pc1)
plot(pc2)


Thanks, this is brilliant! As a follow up, is there a way to plot a curve for the power as the sample size increases? I've seen this with other packages and I see an example here (https://humburg.github.io/Power-Analysis/simr_power_analysis.html), but I am unsure how to do this with the random intercept as you've laid out.

There is, you can use the powerCurve (see my edit). If you try this, you may want to initially include a command nsim=50 or so inside the powerSim/powerCurve functions to see it works correctly (default number of simulations is 1000 which may take a long time). of course for actual power calculations use a large number of simulations such as 1000 or 5000.

Awesome, thank you so much! This is truly helpful! I'm very grateful for your support!

I'm glad I could help!
